# How to check the color code of my line numbering?

Tags: colorcolumn

I currently have the setting `set colorcolumn` enabled in my config file, and I have found out that I can change it using `highlight ColorColumn guibg=#hexcode`. I want the coloring of the column to match the color of my line numbering. So, how do I check the coloring of my line number?

I am using Neovim on a mac terminal if this is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The highlight group used for line numbers is named [LineNr](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#hl-LineNr), so you can use the following command to inspect its current setting:

```
:hi LineNr
```

Additionally, if you want to use the same settings for both, you can *link* the two groups, with:

```
:hi clear ColorColumn
:hi link ColorColumn LineNr
```

See [`:help :hi-link`](https://vimhelp.org/syntax.txt.html#%3Ahi-link) for more details on linking highlight groups.

Comment: Great, thank you!